# SO: what does this css selector mean

Tags: css, css-selectors

When I check the css of SO code, there is one line:

```
.btn - delete {
```

has '-' and spaces inside it, what does this mean?
I don't see this kind of selector in
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like it should be

`.btn-delete`

aka There is no '-' selector